# Defining "quain"

Tags: meaning

In "Kinds of Verse" poet Gerard Manley Hopkins writes

> The former [rhythmic repetition] gives more tone, *candorem*, style, chasteness, the latter [intermittent repetition] more brilliancy, starriness, **quain**, margaretting.

I've looked the web over (by which I mean the freely available online dictionaries, Wordnik, Urban Dictionary, and so forth) and only found definitions on Urban Dictionary. These, though, are multiple, without apparent overlap, and do not seem to fit the usage included here.

Urban Dictionary: *quain*

- "Adjective describing anything that is crazy and out of control."
- "Generous, or very parranoid. [sic]"

I only include these because I have found nothing else. There is of course, the possibility of error in the text, in which case I'd appreciate help determining the intended word. The text appears on page 125 of Everyman's Library's *Hopkins*.

Comment: Sounds like it might be intended to be a humorous formation of a noun to mirror _quaint_, i.e., to mean ‘quaintness’. Not sure what _margaretting_ is either; are Margarets associated with a particular style of rhyme?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've just googled "margaretting" and it only returned the name of a village in Essex. I wonder whether Manley Hopkins had some connection with it?

Comment: Just a guess: Perhaps "margaretting" means a somewhat round-and-round (cyclic) repetition, like plucking petals off a daisy (*marguerite* in French, and perhaps in some British English by extension) - "She loves me, she loves me not,..." (or the French version).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is rare these days that one *requires* access to the OED. Free online dictionaries almost always have at least some entry on any given word, and you’d typically only turn to the OED for a richer etymology or more authoritative citations.

In this case, however:
[image: Screenshot of the OED entry for *quain*]

The definition given is:

> G. M. Hopkins' name for: an **angle, a wedge-like corner**. Also: angularity.

Note that it specifically attributes this usage to Hopkins, as possibly his own coinage or at least affectation.

On how he came up with it, OED speculates

> Origin: Probably a variant or alteration of another lexical item. Etymon: [*quoin* n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156875#eid27191843)

Which itself is defined as:

> 1. Building.
>      a. Originally: an **external angle of a wall**; an outer corner of a building. Subsequently also: any of the stones or bricks serving to form this angle; a cornerstone. Cf. coin n. 1.

Answer (score 2):

Found two references to Quain in an Edwardian guidebook to Norway "Norway and its fjords" by MA Wyllie, pages 248 and 250:
P248: ...bearded russians, englishmen, swedes, germans, QUAINS, finns and lapps fiiled the streets...
P250: ...lapp QUAIN, finn and all sorts of seafarer...
(my capitals)

Obviously a "race" of people but can find no references anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A search of the full text of [The Journals And Papers Of Gerard Manley Hopkins](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.460186/2015.460186.The-Journals_djvu.txt), shows that he uses the word *quain* several times. In one use, he writes:

> Not unapparent that the Matterhorn is like a Greek galley strande 4 , 
>   a reared-up rostrum — the sharp quains or arretes the gunwales...

Other uses seem to be consistent with this use as a straight-lined edge.

This, and *margaretted*, are mentioned in connection with his theories on [Inscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscape_and_instress), so I assume margaretting is also some description of a physical shape.